# Which SPDIF-out bracket do I need?

Tags: motherboard, digital-audio

I've recently noticed my speaker set has an optical input (TOSLINK), but my mainboard ([Gigabyte GA-Z170-HD3P Intel Z170](http://media.gamersnexus.net/images/media/2015/features/motherboards/gigabyte-hd3p-z170.jpg)) has no built-in output on its backplate. It does have a 2-pin SPDIF_O socket though, [as told by the manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170-hd3p_e.pdf) (page 16, section 10). The pin description says SPDIFO and GND.

Therefore, I want to put a bracket onto it to go out of the backside. Only problem is that I cannot seem to find any suitable bracket for this, as all the ones I can find have 3 pins (POWER, SPDIFO, GND).

What do I do here?

Comment: Looks like some comes with separate cables that allows you to use the USB 2.0/1.1 header for +5V.